# Deserialize response of JSON array in a class using POJO

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am trying to fetch the response of the JSON array using the below code. But I am getting com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException. Below is my response.

```
[
    {
        "performanceId": "0P0I",
        "companyId": "007XQ",
        "investmentId": "F0VTK"
    }
]
```

Below is my code

```
public static ObjectMapper getJSONMapper() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return objectMapper;
    }
ValidatableResponse response = given().header("Authorization", token)
                    .header("Content-type", "application/json").body(testCaseBean.getRequest()).when().log().all()
                    .post(EndPoint.SRM_BOB_RIC_API).then().log().all();

            response.assertThat().statusCode(200);
            actualRIOutput = CommonUtils.getJSONMapper()
                    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                    .readValue(response.extract().asString(), BoBSrmRicResponseBean.class);
            System.out.println(actualRIOutput.getRicResponse().get(0).getCompanyId());
```

I am getting the following error.

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.mtar.indexes.bean.BoBSrmRicResponseBean` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
at [Source: (String)"[{"performanceId":"0P00BI","companyId":"0C07XQ","investmentId":"F0SVTK"}]"; line: 1, column: 1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1601)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1375)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1322)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializer.java:640)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:221)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:197)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4593)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3548)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3516)

The Bean I am constructing is as follows.

```
 @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    public class RICMappingResponseBean {
        private String performanceId;
        private String companyId;
        private String investmentId;
    }

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class BoBSrmRicResponseBean {
    List<RICMappingResponseBean> ricResponse;
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Well ... your bean is describing a JSON in the following structure: `{ "ricResponse" : [ { ... }, { ... } ] }`. That does not match your incoming JSON.

Comment: The error is clearly telling you what the problem is. `Cannot deserialize value of type com.mtar.indexes.bean.BoBSrmRicResponseBean from Array value`. You have a JSON array (the `[ ]`), and you are trying to put it inside a `BobSrmRicResponseBean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON example has an array. While you are trying to deserialize it into an object, `BobSrmRicResponseBean` which has a field `ricResponse`, which is not featured in the JSON.
Either change your JSON to:

```
{
  "ricResponse": [  {
        "performanceId": "0P0I",
        "companyId": "007XQ",
        "investmentId": "F0VTK"
    } ]
}
```

Or otherwise deserialize the list separately:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = CommonUtils.getJSONMapper()                    
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

 CollectionType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory()
      .constructCollectionType(List.class, RICMappingResponseBean.class);

 List<RICMappingResponseBean> list = mapper.readValue(response.extract().asString(), javaType);
```